# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException' with message 'Could not resolve host: 0

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am attempting to do a simple, delete all recordings and I keep getting this error thrown:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException' with message 'Could not
>   resolve host: 0' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\twilio-php-master\Twilio\Http\CurlClient.php:41 Stack
>   trace: #0

code using is below, please help!

```
<?php
    require_once 'twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;
    // Set our AccountSid and AuthToken
    $sid = 'MYSID';
    $token = 'MYTOKEN';

    // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
    $client = new Client($sid, $token);

    foreach ($client->account->recordings->getPage(0, 50, array('DateCreated>' => '2011-07-05 08:00:00', 'DateCreated<' => '2011-08-01')) as $recording) {
        echo $recording->sid." -- ". $recording->date_created . "\n";
        $client->account->recordings->delete($recording->sid);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: According to the code, it looks like `getPage()` is looking for `$targetUrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[The `getPage` method only takes a single argument, `$targetUrl`.](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/RecordingList.php#L122-L129)

You likely want to use [`read`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/recording?code-sample=code-get-all-recordings-for-an-account&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x) instead, which will load all the recordings into a list that you can then loop over and delete.

```
foreach ($client->account->recordings->read(array('DateCreated>' => '2011-07-05 08:00:00', 'DateCreated<' => '2011-08-01')) as $recording) {
    echo $recording->sid." -- ". $recording->date_created . "\n";
    $client->recordings($recording->sid)->delete();
}
```

Comment: Ok, getting there! It's trying!    Now getting:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\RecordingList::delete() in C:\xampp\htdocs\deleteallrecordings.php on line 14

Comment: Ah, apologies, didn't notice that bit was wrong. I've updated my answer, but you need `$client->recordings($recording->sid)->delete();`.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries! Would you mind accepting the answer so that other people can see it helped too? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Final result, works great!! Thank you again philnash

```
<?php
require_once('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once 'twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
// Set our AccountSid and AuthToken
$sid = 'SID';
$token = 'TOKEN';

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

foreach ($client->account->recordings->read(array('DateCreated>' => '2017-09-01 08:00:00', 'DateCreated<' => '2017-10-13')) as $recording) {
    echo $recording->sid." -- ". $recording->dateCreated->format('y/m/d') . "\n";
    $client->recordings($recording->sid)->delete();
}
?>
```